# How to check key value of array to prevent duplicate entry in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I know this is a very common and repeated subject, but after spending some hours of googling I didn't find the right solution for my problem.

Using a `foreach` loop I'm filling an array, each row including a key and value. I just want to prevent `duplicates` or remove them.

```
$data['products'] = array();
$data['stores'] = array();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    //if (!in_array($product['store_id'], $data['stores'])) {
    if (!array_key_exists($product['store_id'], $data['stores'])) {
        $data['stores'][] = array(
            'store_id'   => $product['store_id'],
            'store_name' => $product['store_name']
        );
    }
}
```

The result of `print_r($data['stores'])`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 1
            [store_name] => Karaca
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 1
            [store_name] => Karaca
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 7
            [store_name] => nurteks
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 7
            [store_name] => nurteks
        )
)
```

I tried all suggestions, but I don't know how to figure it out.
Thanks for any kind help!

Comment: Is this `$products` being generated by an sql resultset? If so, please post that query.  `$data ['products']` doesn't need to be in your question -- you don't use it.  Please post the full data that is in `$products`.  I have a sneaking suspicion that you have received fast/poor answers  (in a hurry to earn rep points) that have not considered what is best for you, your project, and future SO readers.  After posting this critical information, you may discover a more professional method to employ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the store ID as the key in the stores array. This will ensure that the entries are unique since array keys are inherently unique.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $data['stores'][$product['store_id']] = array(
        'store_id'   => $product['store_id'],
        'store_name' => $product['store_name']
    );
}
```

The two things you tried didn't work because:

1. `if (!in_array($product['store_id'], $data['stores'])) {...`
   The "needle" (`$product['store_id']`) is an integer, but the "haystack" (`$data['stores']`) contains arrays.
2. `if (!array_key_exists($product['store_id'], $data['stores'])) {`
   You aren't specifying array keys when you use `$data['stores'][]` to append items, so the store id won't be found as an array key, or if it is, it won't *really* be the store id, it will just be the automatically assigned sequential index that just coincidentally matches a store id.

Comment: OMG! I really appreciate for your help! That was so easy and I spend so long time for it!!!? :-(

Comment: Of course I'll. I'm waiting for time limit... 3 min is left.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be saving the store Ids and test if it's exist or not

```
$storeIds = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if(!empty( $storeIds[$product['store_id']])){
        //the store is taken before
    }else{
        // new store
        $data['stores'][] = array(
            'store_id'   => $product['store_id'],
            'store_name' => $product['store_name']
        );
    }
    $storeIds[$product['store_id']] = true;//save the store id

}
```